# How can I return a for loop output as a String array?

Tags: java

Instead of my for loop printing the output id, I would like it to return the output into a String array that I can use later in my main method. Is this possible?

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FizzBuzz runit = new FizzBuzz();
        runit.run(20);

    }

    void run(int highestnumber) {

        System.out.println("FizzBuzz will run until: " + highestnumber);
        System.out.println();

        for (int a = 0; a < highestnumber; a++) {

            if (a % 3 == 0 && a % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
            }

            else if (a % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Fizz");
            } else if (a % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Buzz");
            } else {
                System.out.println(a);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It indeed is possible, what have you tried so far? Have you ever heard of [String Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)?

Comment: @AshvinSharma That is really not a good fit for a StringBuilder. He explicitly asks for an array with all the different strings coming back. A StringBuilder doesnt give you that, it only gives you **one** "flat" string in the end.

Comment: I thought list of String literals consumes the permgen which is not good for JVM? @GhostCat

Comment: @GhostCat If Array is only solution then it is good but as OP asked solution then there are many ways to do that and he is free to opt any one. may after some guide he can change his mind to either using StringBulider or StringBuffer in directive of code optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can return a String array form the runit method, as `public String[] runit`. Create an empty `arrayList` in the runit method, in each for loop instead of just printing add the value in `ArrayList`.

When for loop terminates convert this `ArrayList` to `String` `Array` and return it.

Comment: You're returning a `String[]` but creating an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Creating an arraylist since defining an array at beginning and adding values might result in `Array IndexOutOfBoundsException` in some scenario, hence creating an `ArrayList` which needs to be converted in array before returning using `Arrays.asList('yourlistname')`

Comment: Why not returning the ArrayList or properly initialize the array then?

Comment: Because he needs an array as his return type, it can definitely be done using ArrayList but returning what @VeryJazzy needs.

Comment: Ok he needs an Array so why initialize an ArrayList which needs to be importet?

Comment: Importing is not an issue it's `java.util` package only and won't impact his code anyways.

Comment: It's just overkill. There is no ArrayList needed to solve this problem. It's kinda overkill when an simple String[] is sufficent and it even is the return value

Comment: It is not overkill since if in future his requirement changes and has to use anything other than highestNumber in this case each time he would be required to change the array size which I don't believe is good practice.

Comment: That's definitly not true

Comment: @psingh If there is an extra parameter that is required in the future you would need to change the implementation anyway.  Creating a `List` for no reason on a problem that already has a _fixed_ size AND explicitly requires an array is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the other answers are overkill. There is no need to use an `ArrayList` for this. Just initialize an array as you allready know how large it will be.

Further on i made the method private. You should always make your methods "as private as possible".

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FizzBuzz runit = new FizzBuzz();
        String[] result = runit.run(20);
        for (String s : result) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private String[] run(int highestnumber) {
        String[] ret = new String[highestnumber];
        System.out.println("FizzBuzz will run until: " + highestnumber);
        System.out.println();

        for (int a = 0; a < highestnumber; a++) {
            if (a % 3 == 0 && a % 5 == 0) {
                ret[a] = "FizzBuzz";
            } else if (a % 3 == 0) {
                ret[a] = "Fizz";
            } else if (a % 5 == 0) {
                ret[a] = "Buzz";
            } else {
                ret[a] = Integer.toString(a);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why convert to `String` from `int` that way instead of using `Integer.toString(a)` which is called from the overloaded method you used anyway?

Answer (score -2):

Of course you can, do it like this:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FizzBuzz runit = new FizzBuzz();
        String[] stuff = runit.run(20);
        for(String s : stuff) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public String[] run(int highestnumber) {
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("FizzBuzz will run until: " + highestnumber);
        System.out.println();

        for (int a = 0; a < highestnumber; a++) {

            if (a % 3 == 0 && a % 5 == 0) {
            output.add("FizzBuzz");
            }

            else if (a % 3 == 0) {
                output.add("Fizz");
            } else if (a % 5 == 0) {
                output.add("Buzz");
            } else {
                output.add(""+a);
            }
        }

        String[] outputArray = output.toArray(new String[0]);

        return outputArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Deja vue. Cool. He will learn a lot from other people doing his homework. Especially given that various things you do in there are either not required, or bad practice.

Comment: Such as how the array will always be the same size as `highestnumber` so you can easily work directly with array but instead you create a `List` just to convert it back to an array.